# Get number of results in separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a list of all products with a certain criteria, but I would also like the # of results in a separate column.  For example, here's the result I'm trying to get:

```
item   price   results
test   2.02    3
test   2.10    3
test   2.50    3
```

Since there are 3 rows, the results column is 3 for all rows.  Here's my query which won't work:

```
SELECT item, price, count(item) as results
FROM item_list
WHERE item = 'test'
GROUP BY item, price
```

It returns the following:

```
item   price   results
test   2.02    1
test   2.10    1
test   2.50    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
create table ItemMaster(item varchar(20), price decimal(18, 2))

insert into ItemMaster Values
('test',   2.02),
('test',   2.10),
('test',   2.50)

Select item, 
   price, 
   count(item) over (partition by item) as results
from ItemMaster
```

Output

```
item    price   results
-----------------------
test    2.02    3
test    2.10    3
test    2.50    3
```

[Db<>Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be34d60bd9005ea71b00ed4f70213006)